# Concatenate an array with 2 different useEffect calls react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make two different api calls -- get the array results and then concatenate them together into 1 array, which I then present in the return.

I am having difficulty with :

a) There are two calls so the array is populated 2x or

b) The data is not persisted so I lose it between calls.

The goal is to make 2 calls to the api (each once) and concatenate the arrays together into 1 result -- which is cleared or emptied between page refresh.  So it is not called more than once ... or is not continuously lengthened.

My code is as follows:

```
 const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStories();
    getContributions();
  }, []);

  const getStories = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/stories/admin`); // get the data
    setResults((currentArray) => [...currentArray, ...data]);
  };

  const getContributions = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/contributions/admin`);
    setResults((currentArray) => [...currentArray, ...data]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadBootstrap() {
      const bootstrap = await import(
        "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap"
      );

      var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
      );
      var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
      });
    }

    loadBootstrap();
  }, []);

 return (<>       {JSON.stringify(results)}
</>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fetch them both and then set the result **once**.

Something like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getStoriesAndContributions();
}, []);

const getStoriesAndContributions = async () => {
  const [{ data: stories }, { data: contributions }] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get(`/api/stories/admin`),
    axios.get(`/api/contributions/admin`),
  ]);

  setResults([...stories, ...contributions]);
};
```

The [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is not really needed, just in order to make it parallel.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! It works splendidly ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite get what you mean when listing the problems, but why not simply do:

```
const loadArrayElements = async () => {
    const { data: stories } = await axios.get(`/api/stories/admin`);
    const { data: contributions } = await axios.get(`/api/contributions/admin`);
    setState([...stories, ...contributions]);
}

useEffect(() => void loadArrayElements(), []);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is fetch and store the two data sources in javascript variables and call the setState one time in the useEffect :

```
 useEffect( async () => {
    fetchData()
  }, []);

const fetchData = async () => {
  const { data:stories } = await axios.get(`/api/stories/admin`);
  const { data:contributions } = await axios.get(`/api/contributions/admin`);
  setResults([...stories, ...contributions])
}
```